# How to write code to print n accept order of matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How to write this code in Matlab:

```
printf("\nEnter the order m x n of the sparse matrix\n");

scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
```

Can anyone help me how to convert this code in Matlab?

In matlab I write `printf` as `disp('enter the order of the matrix');`
How do print the value?
I want this `printf` output at runtime. How do I do it?
Actually, I am writing a code in Matlab to accept all  matrix order `M*N` like this:

```
enter the order of the matrix
2*3
```

Which should then assign a `2*3` matrix. Then I enter the value.

Comment: Please review [this information on How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) very carefully! Use appropriate language and formatting. When you expect others to spend time on helping you, be courteous enough to spend some of your time on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
disp('Enter the order of the m x n of the sparse matrix');
m=input('Enter m: ');
n=input('Enter n: ');
disp([num2str(m),'*',num2str(n)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% Enter No.of Rows 
m = input('Enter number of rows: '); 
% Enter No.of Rows 
n = input('Enter number of columns: '); 

% Iterate over rows 
for i = 1:m 
   % Iterate over columns
   for j = 1:n  
      % Accept an Element and convert it into number format 
      a(i,j) =str2num(input('Enter Element :')); 
   end 
end
```

Comment: *thanku* !but **when i enter the elements i get a error-Error in ==> str2num at 32
if ~ischar(S) || ndims(s)>2**